# What does Default Implementation of Python means in CPython?

Tags: python, c, cpython

I have started learning python and there's a concept of flavors of python in which first is CPython and it's defination is that it is default implementation of Python. Now here i don't understand what it is trying to say, is that - full python is implemented in c language or is that only something is implemented of python in c language. Please figure out confusion among these.

Comment: It is saying that the full programming language is implemented in C, but there are also other versions of Python which are written in other languages (for example PyPy, which implements Python in Python). CPython, the one written in C, is the one most people use as it is often the fastest.

Comment: Cpython is the official implementation of the Python interpreter.

Comment: Hey, but people use it for what specific language. I mean to say that you are saying that people uses it often, but for what - c or python. Cause it is written in c but implemented from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [one group of developers](https://www.python.org/psf-landing/) which work on the Python language. The "Python language" *could* just be an abstract specification of how the language is supposed to behave, with no actual runnable project. But that's not what those Python developers do; they produce the "Python language" both in the [abstract](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) as a series of [suggestions](https://peps.python.org) and [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/), but they also implement that in the [CPython](https://www.python.org/downloads/) language. CPython is an implementation of the Python language, written in C. "The Python language" in the abstract (specifications, documentation) and in its actual implementation in the form of CPython go hand in hand.

There are *other* groups of developers implementing alternative versions of the Python language; they behave the same (for the most part) in that they can execute Python code conforming to the abstract language definition, but the Python implementation is not the aforementioned CPython, but something else.

Comment: Hmm, got you ! thanks for easy explanation.

Answer (score 1):

CPython is the name of a particular implementation of the language Python, and with default they mean this is the one you most likely want to use.  Other implementations include PyPy, Stackless and MicroPython.

Comment: Huh, but lecdi is saying that it is fully implemented.

Comment: @Vishu You will have to clarify what you mean.  My point is that it's not necessarily "C" as the language c that is important, but that's it's a name to differentiate between Python the language and the CPython the particular implementation.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Gotcha !

Comment: Also, CPython 3.10.4 (latest) version have some parts implemented in Python particular libraries.